# Drag a div or image into textarea and put a value inside it

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to put a value inside `textarea` by allowing user to drag a `div` or `image` into it.

Here is roughly what my html looks like.

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}

.emote {
  position:relative;
  background-color:rgba(45,45,45, 0.3);
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.emote .emoteTitle {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="emote">
<img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ficons.iconarchive.com%2Ficons%2Fpaomedia%2Fsmall-n-flat%2F512%2Fcat-icon.png&f=1" alt="emote1" title="emote1" class="emoteImage">
<span class="emoteTitle">emote1</span>
</div>

<div class="emote">
<img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fes.seaicons.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F06%2Fsign-check-icon.png&f=1" alt="emote2" title="emote2" class="emoteImage">
<span class="emoteTitle">emote2</span>
</div>

<textarea></textarea>
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qna4jqL0/9/)

So when user drags a div.emote or the image onto text area i want it to put either emote1 or emote2 into it.

What would be the best way to make this work?

Comment: From what I know is that you actually can't insert images into inputs. But you could give a try "Raw emojis" or try to have some emojis with unicodes that you are going to insert into your input. Example : 

Comment: Not asking to put an image but value of its attribute ( emote1 or emote2) @SupremeDEV

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: Think you would need to use a content editable div

Answer (score 3):

Here is a snippet that builds on yours.
When you drop the image on the textarea, its alt text will be added at the cursor position.

You can easily change this to put any value you want, just replace the second argument on `.setData('text', emoteImage.alt)`

For reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragstart
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.emoteImage').forEach((emoteImage) => {
  emoteImage.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', emoteImage.alt);
    event.effectAllowed = "copy";
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}

.emote {
  position:relative;
  background-color:rgba(45,45,45, 0.3);
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.emote .emoteTitle {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="emote">
<img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ficons.iconarchive.com%2Ficons%2Fpaomedia%2Fsmall-n-flat%2F512%2Fcat-icon.png&f=1" alt="emote1" title="emote1" class="emoteImage">
<span class="emoteTitle">emote1</span>
</div>

<div class="emote">
<img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fes.seaicons.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F06%2Fsign-check-icon.png&f=1" alt="emote2" title="emote2" class="emoteImage">
<span class="emoteTitle">emote2</span>
</div>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified last example from: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

This is just a quick template, but I hope you'll know how to modify it further

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.innerHTML = document.getElementById(data).dataset.value;
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" data-value="img1" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>

<textarea id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer from NoOorZ24 here is the final draft. 
JsFiddle link: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ddyfdmk/)

> HTML

```
<div id="div1" class="emote">
  <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ficons.iconarchive.com%2Ficons%2Fpaomedia%2Fsmall-n-flat%2F512%2Fcat-icon.png&f=1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="emote1" title="emote2" class="emoteImage" data-value="img1" id="drag1"
    width="88" height="31">
  <span class="emoteTitle">emote1</span>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="emote">
  <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fes.seaicons.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F06%2Fsign-check-icon.png&f=1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="emote2" title="emote2" class="emoteImage" data-value="img2" id="drag2"
    width="88" height="31">
  <span class="emoteTitle">emote2</span>
</div>

<textarea id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></textarea>
```

> Script

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.innerHTML = document.getElementById(data).dataset.value;
}
```